# Object invoking in for new operator overloading

Tags: c++

I am familiar with the concept that an object is required (if a friend function isn't used) to invoke the overloaded operator.

For example:

```
Test obj1,obj2; //some initialization already done
obj1 + obj2; // for complier it is translated as obj1.operator+(obj2)
```

But in case of overloading `operator new`

```
Test *ptr = new Test;
```

Who invokes the call??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer:  the compiler does.

In more detail, given

```
Test *ptr = new Test;
```

the compiler needs visibility of the complete definition of `Test` in order to instantiate it using the new expression (`new Test`).  The compiler will give a diagnostic (in this case, a compilation error in practice) when it doesn't have that visibility.

The definition of a `class` or `struct` type includes, among other things, any declarations of any `operator new()` functions it provides.   Since the compiler has complete visibility of that, it can decide what version of `operator new()` needs to be called.

Given that information, the compiler emits the appropriate code to call the appropriate overload of `operator new()` to obtain memory, and then to initialise that memory using a constructor.    It also emits code to handle error conditions (for example, giving required behaviour if the `operator new()` or the constructor throws an exception).

No object (instance of `Test`) is required to call `operator new()`, since `operator new()` is called before the object is even constructed.   This is different from operators like `operator+()` which operate on two existing objects.

Answer (score 2):

Let's separate things into proper terms:

When you write `new Test`, it is a "new expression". The semantics of the new expression is to call the appropriate allocation function (an overload of `operator new`) and initialize an object in the memory it allocates.

So the **expression** you wrote, is what calls the overloaded **operator** function.

Answer (score 0):

When you call *new* (overloaded or not), you are constructing an object, so there is no object yet, and you can not answer the question "which object invokes the call?".

When you create an object of a specified class (on heap or stack) one of the constructors of that class is called. 
When the *new* operator is overloaded, the overloaded *new* will be used to allocate required memory for that object.

The caller is not an object of that class!